# OpenVPN DNS resolving broken on MacOS Sonoma

Tags: wifi, vpn, dns

I've been Googling and even talking to the Apple technical support for days in regards of something that clearly doesn't work in Sonoma (but used to work in Big Sur and Ventura).

The DNS resolver of MacOS seems to completely ignore the DNS server set up by my OpenVPN connection, also the lookup domain. I've checked scutil --dns (preference is alright), and as you can find in many other threads from years ago:

- ping [internal DNS] -> unknown host
- dig [internal DNS] -> resolved
- nslookup [internal DNS] -> resolved

I saw in Google the command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep -i domain` which returns:

```
$ ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep -i domain
domain_name (string): box
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {62.117.5.126, 217.68.162.126}
```

That's the DHCP of my home router.

That being said, the VPN connection is properly tunnelling and I can indeed do `ping [internal IP]` without problem.

The OpenVPN server is running on a Pfsense+ instance, with the nameservers properly set up.

I've looked into `dnsmasq` and it actually resolves the nameservers, however I find the solution "a bit" dirty and I was wondering if there is anyone with similar experiences but maybe more expertise in DNS configuration that may aid me in this matter?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any other person struggling with Apple's DNS resolving: after struggling for weeks and trying all solutions available on the Internet, [VPN / DNS Issues With macOS Ventura](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254321365?answerId=258110962022&sortBy=best#258110962022) on Apple's official forum gave me the key.

Two solutions, you choose:

- Use DNSmasq as a daemon to replace all DNS resolutions

OR

- `sudo mkdir /etc/resolver`
- Create a file under `/etc/resolver/<your domain>` (example: `/etc/resolver/stackexchange.com`) and write in it `nameserver [nameserver IP]`
- Then a simple `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to flush the DNS cache will start resolving your packets :)

Comment: There is no `/etc/resolver` on MacOS Sonoma...

Comment: Create the folder with sudo mkdir /etc/resolver first.

Comment: I've edited my comment adding the folder creation :). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: FWIW, running dnsmasq works very well.  (At least on versions up to macOS 12 Monterey; haven't yet tried later versions, though I strongly suspect it'll still work.)  You can install it through HomeBrew, autostart it with a LaunchAgent, and specify `127.0.0.1` as the DNS in your network settings.  (OS updates usually blat the network settings, so you have to remember to do that last bit again.)  dnsmasq is powerful and really good at handling a _huge_ list of hostnames, if you want to blackhole adservers, trackers, etc.

Comment: I can confirm this works as expected on Macos Sonoma. One note, `dig` won't show any info about the domain, but a `ping` command will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. First of all: dig et.al are not the whole truth on macOS. Many applications (like your browser, for example) use macOS' internal APIs. You can look at your actual DNS configuration by running `scutil --dns` and resolve a hostname using `dns-sd -G v4v6 my-hostname.example.com`.

That being said, although scutil showed the seemingly correct DNS configuration (i.e. the VPN's DNS servers), DNS resolution still did not work correctly. Apparently, "iCloud Private Relay" was enabled automatically and inserted another DNS resolver that was invisible to scutil. As soon as I disabled iCloud Private Relay, DNS resolution worked as expected.

Comment: I actually tried that as well and I didn't get anywhere (even rebooted computer). The solution I posted is extremely weird but does the job in one of the least intrusive ways I've found. Thanks for your reply and the advice!